# What type i should pass to my imageIcon props in react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, ecmascript-6

What props type i can use instead this *any* in my component for imageIcon (I know that this any is working but that's not good practice). I'm using typescript with react. I try everything else including string but that's not working

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import Grid from '../../hoc/layout/Grid';
import styles from './InfoBox.module.scss';

import { SvgIcon } from '@material-ui/core';

interface Props {
  title: string;
  imageIcon?: any;
  userNumber: number;
  content: string;
}

const InfoBox: FC<Props> = ({
  title,
  imageIcon,
  userNumber,
  content,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Grid xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <div className={styles.Boxheader}>
        <div className={styles.ImageHolder}>
          <SvgIcon component={imageIcon} />
        </div>
        <p className={styles.BoxheaderTitle}>{title}</p>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.Boxcontent}>
        <p className={styles.Usernumber}>{userNumber}</p>
        <p className={styles.BoxcontentText}>{content}</p>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default InfoBox;
```

So i can forward this infoBox to other component:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import Layout from '../../hoc/layout/Dashboard';
import InfoBox from '../../components/InfoBox';
import AccountBoxOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountBoxOutlined';
const Settings: FC = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <InfoBox
        title="Total Users"
        userNumber={4456}
        content="+22 in last week"
        imageIcon={AccountBoxOutlinedIcon}
      />
      <InfoBox
        title="Total Users"
        userNumber={4456}
        content="+22 in last week"
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};
export default Settings;
```

Comment: Should be `elementType`

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `SvgIconProps`

```
import { SvgIconProps } from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';

interface Props {
  title: string;
  imageIcon?: SvgIconProps;
  userNumber: number;
  content: string;
}
```

Comment: And what i should add as type of imageIcon?

Comment: I thought it was obvious to use SvgIconProps. I updated my answer to include the interface

Comment: Tnx but still not work... i get this error when hover over component
"The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component."

Comment: I dont have a project setup now with material-ui, is this error on the interface or in the call at the other component? If it's the later try using it like  ` <InfoBox
        title="Total Users"
        userNumber={4456}
        content="+22 in last week"
        imageIcon={<AccountBoxOutlinedIcon />}
      />`

Answer (score 0):

use `typeof SvgIcon`

```
import SvgIcon from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";

interface Props {
  imageIcon?: typeof SvgIcon;
  title?: string;
}
```

[example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-l7vj9)

Comment: Still getting same error when hover on component
"(JSX attribute) component: React.ElementType<any>
The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } &..."
there is no strict mode in sandbox :/